# Need help translating a python script to vba

Tags: python, excel, vba

I want to translate the following python function to VBA so I can use it on vanilla Microsoft Excel:

```py
def valid_sub(cell_range):
    block_a = ['Biology', 'Sociology', 'Further Maths', 'Fine Art', 'Music']
    already_choosen_a = False

    block_b = ['Textiles', 'English', 'Maths', 'BTEC Science', 'BTEC Health and Social Care']
    already_choosen_b = False

    block_c = ['Photography', 'Physics', 'History', 'Psychology', 'BTEC Sport', 'BTEC Performing Arts']
    already_choosen_c = False

    block_d = ['Chemistry', 'Politics', 'Business', 'BTEC Sport']
    already_choosen_d = False

    block_e = ['French', 'Spanish', 'Resit Maths', 'Resit English']
    already_choosen_e = False

    for cell in cell_range:
        if cell in block_a and not already_choosen_a:
            already_choosen_a = True

        elif cell in block_b and not already_choosen_b:
            already_choosen_b = True

        elif cell in block_c and not already_choosen_c:
            already_choosen_c = True

        elif cell in block_d and not already_choosen_d:
            already_choosen_d = True

        elif cell in block_e and not already_choosen_e:
            already_choosen_e = True

        else:
            return 'Not valid subject selection'
    return 'Valid subject selection'
```

I tried the following code, but I get an error that says "unvalid qualifier" (roughly translated from Spanish). I think there are other errors as well, I'm new to VBA.

```
Function valid_sub(cell_range As Range)
    Dim a() As Variant: a = [{"Biology", "Sociology", "Further Maths", "Fine Art", "Music"}]
    Dim choosenA As Boolean
    choosenA = False
    Dim b() As Variant: b = [{"Textiles", "English", "Maths", "BTEC Science", "BTEC Health and Social Care"}]
    Dim choosenB As Boolean
    choosenB = False
    Dim c() As Variant: c = [{"Photography", "Physics", "History", "Psychology", "BTEC Sport", "BTEC Performing Arts"}]
    Dim choosenC As Boolean
    choosenC = False
    Dim d() As Variant: d = [{"Chemistry", "Politics", "Business", "BTEC Sport"}]
    Dim choosenD As Boolean
    choosenD = False
    Dim e() As Variant: e = [{"French", "Spanish", "Resit Maths", "Resit English"}]
    Dim choosenE As Boolean
    choosenE = False
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In cell_range
        If a.Contains(cell) And Not already_choosenA Then
            choosenA = True
        ElseIf b.Contains(cell) And Not choosenB Then
            choosenB = True
        ElseIf c.Contains(cell) And Not choosenC Then
            choosenC = True
        ElseIf d.Contains(cell) And Not choosenD Then
            choosenD = True
        ElseIf e.Contains(cell) And Not choosenE Then
            choosenE = True
        Else:
            Return 'Not valid subject selection'
    Return 'Valid subject selection'

End Function
```

Sorry for the bad code, I wanted to make it as simple as possible so it's easier to translate.

Answer (score 0):

`d.Contains(cell)` is belong to ***.Net*** not ***VBA***

so try this

```
Function valid_sub(cell_range As Range)
    Dim a() As Variant: a = [{"Biology", "Sociology", "Further Maths", "Fine Art", "Music"}]
    Dim choosenA As Boolean
    choosenA = False
    Dim b() As Variant: b = [{"Textiles", "English", "Maths", "BTEC Science", "BTEC Health and Social Care"}]
    Dim choosenB As Boolean
    choosenB = False
    Dim c() As Variant: c = [{"Photography", "Physics", "History", "Psychology", "BTEC Sport", "BTEC Performing Arts"}]
    Dim choosenC As Boolean
    choosenC = False
    Dim d() As Variant: d = [{"Chemistry", "Politics", "Business", "BTEC Sport"}]
    Dim choosenD As Boolean
    choosenD = False
    Dim e() As Variant: e = [{"French", "Spanish", "Resit Maths", "Resit English"}]
    Dim choosenE As Boolean
    choosenE = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In cell_range
        If IsContains(a, cell.Value) And Not already_choosen_a Then
            choosenA = True
        ElseIf IsContains(b, cell.Value) And Not already_choosen_b Then
            choosenB = True
        ElseIf IsContains(c, cell.Value) And Not already_choosen_c Then
            choosenC = True
        ElseIf IsContains(d, cell.Value) And Not already_choosen_d Then
            choosenD = True
        ElseIf IsContains(e, cell.Value) And Not already_choosen_e Then
            choosenE = True
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function IsContains(arr, itm As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each e In arr
        If e = itm Then
            IsContains = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
End Function
```